# Function overwrites the same object every time: how can I avoid this?

Tags: r

I want to create an object for every regression I do (17 of them). The function should ideally create 17 different objects, that I can use afterwards. Currently it is just writing a object on top of the previous one. How can I avoid that? It would be best, if the object is partly named after the particular "filename", to be able to distinguish them afterwards.

```
  dat <- read.csv(file = filename)
  reg2<<- lm(dat[,17]~dat[,6]+dat[,7])
  }

for (f in filenames) {
    upload(f)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the biggest problems with global assignment `<<-` inside a function. Have your function `return()` the model, not assign, and do the assignment *outside* the function.

```
# function returns the result, doesn't assign it
upload <- function(filename) {
  dat <- read.csv(file = filename)
  lm(dat[,17]~dat[,6]+dat[,7])
}

# assignment happens outside the function (like almost every other R function)
# this way you can use whatever name you want
reg2 <- upload("hello.csv")
reg3 <- upload("world.csv")

# or use a for loop
reg <- list()
for (f in filenames) {
  reg[[f]] <- upload(f)
}

# or use lapply for the same effect more concisely
reg <- lapply(filenames, upload)
names(reg) = filenames)

# You can now access individual list elements with [[
summary(reg[["hello.csv"]])

# Or extract all the model summary stats into a nice data frame
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(reg, broom::glance))
```